# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property "CallerContextProperty" on null

Tags: php

I recently upgraded from php 7 to 8 and I have a problem with this class

```
class CallerContext {
    public function __construct ($val,$key) {
        $this->wrappedProperties->CallerContextProperty->value = $val;
        $this->wrappedProperties->CallerContextProperty->key = $key;
    }
}
```

throwing this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property "CallerContextProperty" on null

Comment: `$this->wrappedProperties` is null. It looks like you haven't initialized it